# Using an update query to update forms based on values in a text box access

Tags: ms-access

I was wondering if it would be possible to enter numerical data in a text box in a form, click an update button which would run an update query and add values a and b in the form to values a and b in the table. What I have so far is

```
Private Sub Command32_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "updaterquery"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

On the button and for the update query

[Forms]![updater]![idtbox]

[Forms]![updater]![salestbox]

[Forms]![updater]![retentionstbox]

These are under the "Criteria" section of the update query, and that is all I have got so far.

Any advice would be fantastic thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easy enough to test: the approach sounds reasonable - give it a try, you won't break anything!  Of course the data on the form would need to conform to the data integrity & validation requirements of the table you are inserting into.  I guess you should paste the SQL from your query for completeness and also indicate what specific problems you are facing when you try out your approach.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm not worried about testing as this has no true data in yet, when I click my update button I get an error stating "Run time error '3270': Property not found." and when I debug I get "DoCmd.OpenQuery "updaterquery"" Highlighted. If I just click on the run command on the actual updaterquery I get "Query must have at least one destination field."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided to my previous answer, I believe the best way to do this would be to have textboxes on your form that are set to invisible (i.e. [pstntxtbox]).  Have those textboxes linked directly to the table.  Then, set up more textboxes that are actually visible (i.e. [pstntxtbox2]).  These are the textboxes that will have the numbers you're going to enter.  In the query, set it up like this (changing the textbox names to whatever you actually use):

```
UPDATE Sales SET PSTNSALES = (([Forms]![updater]![pstntxtbox]) + ([Forms]![updater]![pstntxtbox2])), 
BBSALES = (([Forms]![updater]![bbtxtbox]) + ([Forms]![updater]![bbtxtbox2])), 
INFSALES = (([Forms]![updater]![inftxtbox]) + ([Forms]![updater]![inftxtbox2])), 
C2FUSALES = (([Forms]![updater]![c2futxtbox]) + ([Forms]![updater]![c2futxtbox2])), 
TVSALES = (([Forms]![updater]![tvtxtbox]) + ([Forms]![updater]![tvtxtbox2])) 
WHERE (((Sales.EIN)=[Forms]![updater]![eintbox]);
```

This way, it will add the 2 boxes together; both the original value and the new value.  Then, once you run that update statement, don't forget to refresh the form so the new numbers get pulled into it (i.e. [pstntxtbox] gets populated with the new sum you just created).

Comment: Thanks, I'm struggling to link the textbox to the table field, I've tried both =[Sales]![PSTNSALES] and PSTNSALES, both just display "#Name?".

Comment: Bind the form to the table, and you should just be able to drag-n-drop the fields right onto the form.  Then just set their Visible properties to False.

Comment: That's great, a bunch more problems still but I'll try to solve these myself before I ask. This has all worked fine though thanks very much.